# How to get values from bean in jsp which is stored in map.Map returning bean object properly

Tags: java, servlets, jsp-tags

The following is Map objects which contains bean object.

```
hasMap = customerData.getCustomerDetailsMap();
```

I stored 'customer Details Bean' inside Map,and Now i am setting this map to request parameter in servlet and passing to jsp

```
request.setAttribute("customerDataMap", hasMap);
```

retrieving the hashmap in jsp by following code.

```
${customerDataMap[param.value]}
```

using param.value as key i am getting the customer Details object(I am printing the object.i am getting the bean object.).Now i want to retrieve the values from bean in jsp .How can i achieve this in jsp only .

I don't want to send bean object directly to jsp.

Comment: What is your actual issue? Is HashMap paremeterized? Why don't you want to send bean object directly to jsp? Why don't you set just the requrired bean object in request attribute?

Comment: What's the problem with bean.getWHATEVERYOUWANT()?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `${customerDataMap[param.value].objectProperty}` ?

For example `${customerDataMap[param.value].name}`